# How do I get the command line Delphi-2007 compiler to ignore or suppress a particular warning

Tags: delphi-2007, suppress-warnings

I am using Delphi 2007.  I know how to get the IDE compiler to suppress/ignore particular warnings.

But how do I get the command line compiler to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `-W-[WARNING]` option. The following example turns off *W1036 ("Variable %s might not have been initialized")*:

```
dcc32 test.dpr -W-USE_BEFORE_DEF
```

The only way I've found to find out the warning name to use is to create a simple console project in the IDE, add code that will produce the warning you want to identify, and then set the *Project->Options-Compiler-Hints and Warnings* to suppress that warning. Then build your project. Show the Messages window, go to the *Output* tab, <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> to *Select all*, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to copy.

- Create a new console app.

  ```
  program Test1;

  {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

  uses
    SysUtils;

  begin
    WriteLn('Test1');
    ReadLn;
  end.
  ```
- Use *Project->Options->Compiler`->Hints and Warnings*, and turn off the warning(s) you want to suppress.
- Build your test project.
- In the *Output* tab of the *Messages* window, select all (<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> or using the context menu) and copy to the clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or via the context menu).
- In a new Notepad window (or a new editor tab), paste in the contents of the clipboard. You'll find a long block of *dcc32.exe* command line similar (but probably much longer) than this (I've **emphasized** the relevant parts to notice):

> Build started 02/05/2016 2:48:48 PM.
>
> ---
>
> Project "E:\Code\Project1.dproj" (Make target(s)):
>   Target CoreCompile:
>       **c:\rad studio\5.0\bin\dcc32.exe** -DDEBUG;DEBUG -I"c:\rad studio\5.0\lib";"c:\rad studio\5.0\Imports";"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\5.0\Dcp";E:\Code\FastMM4;E:\madCollection\madBasic\BDS4;E:\madCollection\madDisAsm\BDS4;E:\madCollection\madExcept\BDS4;"E:\Code\Virtual Treeview\Source";E:\code\Indy10_5294\Lib\Core;E:\code\Indy10_5294\Lib\System;E:\code\Indy10_5294\Lib\Protocols;
>   **--SNIPPED ANOTHER DOZEN LINES--** --no-config **-W-USE_BEFORE_DEF   Project1.dpr**
>
> Build succeeded.
>      0 Warning(s)
>      0 Error(s)
>   Time Elapsed 00:00:00.12

So as a result of all this, we've identified **USE_BEFORE_DEF** as the warning name for W1036 for use with the command line compiler, as well as illustrated exactly how to supply it to the compiler.

You can, of course, disable more than one warning in  order to identify them; I've just used one for simplicity, and snipped out a lot of the command-line output that is produced.